# Shipping methods disabled in checkout: Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, frontend, shipping-methods

I have an issue with the shipping methods on the checkout page in Magento 1.9. When I add the products into the cart and then try to check out, I notice that the shipping methods displayed are disabled and I am not able to select any of them.

Comment: Your problem was solve?

Comment: No its still there.

Comment: fixed this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please check in admin panel that any shipping method are enabled or not.

**admin -> system -> configuration -> sales -> shipping methods**

If, any shipping method is enabled but not display on checkout.

Please check that your website are multi store. If multi store,  so please check, store wise shipping method and enable.

Hope this will help you!

Comment: The shipping methods are enabled and they are also displayed on the checkout page. The issue is I am not able to select the shipping methods. The radio buttons are disabled and it does not allow to select any of them. Something like this:  https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7497

Comment: ok. If your store live or demo link, please share URL.

Comment: The issue exists in my local installation of Magento 1.9.

Comment: Please check any CSS class or js which working for disable radio button.